# How can I set onClickListener on ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm making class like as below

```
// All necessary imports are here

public class More extends Activity {

    String[] MoreItems = { "Transfers", "Budgets", "Branches", "Tools", "News",
            "Customer Service", "Settings", "Help", "About" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.more_view);

        ListView moreListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.moreListView);
        MoreListAdapter listAdapter = new MoreListAdapter();
        moreListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // accountsTypeListView.setOnItemClickListener(listClickListner);
    }

    class MoreListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        MoreListAdapter() {
            super(More.this, R.layout.list_item, MoreItems);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            } else {
                row = convertView;
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textItem);

            tv.setText(getItem(position));

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

It will generate the List, I want to call respective activities on respective click, like if User click Transfer then it will show transfer Activity, 
How can I call onClickListener on this list and how can I start Activity on click.

Comment: do you want to set the OnClickListener on each item of your ListView or for TextViews of each Item or what ??

Comment: row.setOnClickListener(this); ..... startActivity(this, someIntent);

Answer (score 62, accepted):

you can also do like this..

```
moreListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("############","Items " + MoreItems[arg2] );
    }
});
```

Comment: Place this directly beneath where you have set the adapter at moreListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

Answer (score 49):

There are two option to handle click event for each row.

1) If your class extends `ListActivity`, you can override following method.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  //do something here using the position in the array
}
```

2) Handle click event of row in `getView()` method

```
row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Comment: 2nd method crashes after onclik on the item of searched/refreshed  in list view while calling intent inside the onclick method ! any solution for that?.. the problem comes when we use our own search filter.

Comment: Necro, but the second method would be great if you need to get the screen position of any children in a list item.

Answer (score 15):

For example:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setAdapter(listAdapter); 
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(More.this, NextActvity.class);
        //If you wanna send any data to nextActicity.class you can use
        i.putExtra(String key, value.get(position));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "More" class has to extend ListActivity instead of Activity, then you can override  onListItemClick

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //do something here using the position in the arrya
}
```

**Edit:** Forgot to say, in your layout your `ListView` has to be called

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: and how to set onClick listener on each item?

Comment: Every item will receive the click. you just know which one using the position of the clicked Item e.g. MoreItems[position]

Comment: and should we implement onclicklistner or not?

Comment: no need for it! onListItemClick handle it for every items in your array

Comment: This is the only answer that mentioned the crucial detail that to use the `onListItemClick` override the class must extend `ListActivity`.